# Customizing Create Features window in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcobjects

Can I customize `Create Features window` in ArcMap? (whether by using ArcMap capabilities or by writing ArcMap-Addin)

I've read about [Creating custom ArcMap TOC views](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w4000000), is there something similar for `Create Features window`?

My requirement is to visualize template names (not layer names), in addition to classify templates in tree-like organization.

Comment: I would imagine that this is not possible as you are asking to change the interface of a core part of the desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not customize this dialog. However you can simply create custom FeatureTempalate dialogs. To do so, download this sample project

[Feature Template Select Dialog](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5d43108de6e40a595be2507e57a20d0)

A similar question has been already answered:

[Getting FeatureTemplate dialog form ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138548/getting-featuretemplate-dialog-form-arcobjects/138569)

Comment: Thank you very much @Farid, that is exactly what I wanted.