# Getting FeatureTemplate dialog form ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

Is it possible to access the "Select Feature Template" dialog as shown in the below screenshot through ArcObjects? We can access this dialog when using the Editor -> Copy Parallel tool.

[image]

Comment: IEditTemplate and few related interfaces are in ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto namespace, so look if you can find a ...Dialog in ESRI.ArcGIS.CartoUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this ArcGIS sample that exactly addresses your question:

[Feature Template Select Dialog](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5d43108de6e40a595be2507e57a20d0)

Comment: wow! i don't even have to write a line of code? thank you.